# Joomla looking in wrong directory for localhost

Tags: joomla

This is the first time I've tried to setup Joomla in a localhost dev environment. I have everything setup with Xampp, and when I browse to localhost/mysite, I sort of see my site, but without any styles, images, etc..

In Firebug, I can see that the initial request goes to localhost/mysite, but all the subsequent requests go to just 'localhost'- so I'm getting a bunch of 404's on my CSS, images, etc.

I've tried tinkering around in .htaccess and the root index.php file, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell Joomla to look at localhost/mysite instead of just localhost...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to change the configuration:

```
var $live_site = '';
```

That initially had the actual URL. I changed it to "localhost/mysite" (several variations.) - but because I didn't have http://localhost, it was appending it, instead of replacing it. The request in the NET tab of Firebug indicated the calls were going to "localhost", but in the HTML panel, I could see the inproper URL, and it looked like this..

```
localhost/mysite\localhost\mysite/myfile.css
```

Comment: well, nice for you. Now we all know how to handle this prolem. You deserve a +1.

Comment: FYI you can leave var $live_site = ''; there is no need to put anything in there, it makes your site portable.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla instalation is pretty straightforward.
You don't have to set any .htaccess or whatsoever.
I would advice to test (using phpMyAdmin for example) if you can access 
the joomla DB. 
Did you install the dummy data? If not I would advice to do it.
The better way is to reinstall Joomla. For doing that just delete
de joomla directory and remove the DB created (actually this is 
not necessary).
If you have the dummy data check the permissions of the files,
but I don't hink this is your problem.

Comment: I'm restoring an existing site, not a new site. The installation itself is working. When I pull up localhost/mysite, I get the authentication form, and the HTML text with no formatting. There is something in Joomla telling it to look at localhost instead of localhost/mysite - something in the config? Anyway, I have multiple sites, so I can't just put it in localhost

Comment: ok, I see. Are you using the same Joomla version? Sure, you cannot put it into localhost. Did you try in another machine or another Joomla installation so that you can use directly localhost?

Comment: In Drupal, you can set a base directory - but I don't see anywhere to do that in Joomla..